# fill data frame with apply

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I want to fill a data frame by doing what would do the script below:

```
for(i in 1:3000) {
    adress=grep(nomcusip[i,1],Name2C[,"LName"])
    if(length(adress)>0 && !is.na(length(adress))) {
        for(j in 1:length(adress)) {
            nomcusip[i,1+j]=adress[j]
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the dataframe:

```
    V1
1   2122united natural foods
2   238 telecom limited
3   24 hour fitness
4   24/7 real media 
5   247media
...
```

I am sure there is a way to do that way faster with the apply function but i don't know how to do so.

Could someone tell me?

Many thanks,
Vincent

Comment: Please do `dput(nomcusip)`, or a fraction of it such as `dput(nomcusip[1:5, ])`, to provide a reproducible version of your starting dataframe that we can use (also the `Name2C` variable). You don't provide nearly enough information for us to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks David for your comment. I don't have my R script with me currently, and although I am sure there is a better way to do that with apply I have done something I am happy with thanks to basic loops. Still I'll try do provide some more information this week end.